# Image <input> and table-cell display

Tags: css, newline, tablelayout, css-tables

I have an `<input>` and an `<input type="image">` displayed as `table-cell`.
I cannot figure out why the image is on a new line in WebKit-powered browsers.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    <div id="search_input_wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="Search" id="search_input" />
        <input type="image" name="Submit" id="search_submit" alt="Search" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
div#search {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
div#search_input_wrapper {
    display:table-row;
}
input {
    display:table-cell;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
```

And here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a45pf/)

Comment: No image is specified (the `src` attribute is missing).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It's there in the actual code, no difference though.

Comment: The jsfiddle does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Now that you say that, I do see it in Firefox. But in WebKit browser it does.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem that only pertains to `-webkit` browsers.

If you take a look at this [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/9GaJ2/), you will clearly see the problem. An `input` element with the property `display:table-cell` should normally appear on the same line, as `inline` elements do. You will notice that this is true if `type="submit"`. However, if `type="image"`, then the `input` elements act as `block` level elements, appearing on a new line.

The root of the problem lies with the property `-webkit-appearance`. If you were to apply `-webkit-appearance:none` to both `input` elements, you will notice they now both act the same! [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/9GaJ2/1/)

The default property of an `input` element with `type="submit"` is `-webkit-appearance:push-button` therefore we can solve the problem by applying the same property to the `type="image"` elements, as they normally have the property `-webkit-appearance:none` by default.

Problem solved, [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/9GaJ2/2/).

```
input[type="image"] {
    -webkit-appearance:push-button;
}
```

Here is an updated [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/4E43R/), fixing your initial problem.

I also added a `src` to `input[type="image"]`, as that is the purpose of `type="image"`.

Again, all these pertains to `-webkit` browsers, if you are using IE, FF or Opera, none of these example will mean anything to you, as they don't demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Ho do you infer that the `input` has a width of 100%? There is not such setting in the code.

Comment: That sheds some odd light. Obviously push-button isn't the look I'm going for but I'll figure something out. Answer accepted.